# How to make mongoose not create unnecessary _id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  posts: [{
    title: String,
    body: String,
  }]
})
```

I will get something like

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("xxx"), // which is OK
  "name": "xxx",
  "posts": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("yyy"), // which is what I dont want
    "title": "ttt",
    "body": "bbbb",
  }]
}
```

How can I make mongoose not create the `_id` inside posts?